# Component becoming unmanageable - DRY solution

Tags: reactjs

Can someone please show me a better way to run these button functions. In the example below I have two buttons, however, in the real version, I have lots. This has become unmanageable. I've got coders block and can't seem to figure out an elegant solution. Any help?

```
function DashboardPage() {
  const [showCandidatesComponent, setShowCandidatesComponent] = useState(false);
  const [showEmployersComponent, setShowEmployersComponent] = useState(true);

  function handleViewCandidatesButton(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setShowCandidatesComponent(true);
    setShowEmployersComponent(false);
  }
  function handleViewEmployersButton(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setShowEmployersComponent(true);
    setShowCandidatesComponent(false);
  }

  return (
    <div className="row flex-xl-nowrap">
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={handleViewCandidatesButton}
        className="btn btn-link btn-block text-left"
      >
        Candidates
      </button>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={handleViewEmployersButton}
        className="btn btn-link btn-block text-left"
      >
        Employers
      </button>

      <main>
        {showCandidatesComponent ? <Candidates /> : null}
        {showEmployersComponent ? <Employers /> : null}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: How about moving each button into its own component along with its respective "showXYZComponent" method and handler?

Comment: Sorry, noob question. How does that reduce the repetitive nature of `handleViewEmployersButton` or `handleViewCandidatesButton`?

Comment: I don't think the `buttons` are the issue, I think it's the show hide functions.

Comment: how about creating a mapping of all the buttons handlers 
```[{
  type: 'candidates',
  showHandler: showCandidatesComponent
  setHandler: setCandidatesComponent
},
{
  type: 'employers',
  showHandler: showEmployers Component
  setHandler: setEmployers Component
}
]```

Comment: Do you want your dashboard to show only one view at a time?

Comment: Yes, that's correct @khan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-williams-m1bni)

---

You can create an indexing system for your pages and add the index number that corresponds to each page's button on an HTML attribute, such as `name`.

By doing this, it solves the problem of having each button's `onClick` handler do:

```
setShowCandidatesComponent(true), setShowEmployersComponent(false), ...
```

Since only one view can correspond to an index number, you are eliminating the need to handle all of your boolean values every time a button is clicked.

Now, you can have one generic button handler on your Dashboard component that retrieves indices from `event.target.name` and updates the state. Just make sure to parse `event.target.name` into an integer because it is a string.

---

**DashboardPage.js**

```
const DashboardPage = props => {
  // viewIndex refers to the index in the views array that will be rendered.
  const [viewIndex, setViewIndex] = useState(0);

  // I attached the index to the "name" attribute for each button.
  const handleViewChange = event => setViewIndex(+event.target.name);

  // Get the button labels for each view.
  const buttonLabels = views.map(view => view.name);

  return (
    <div>

      {/* Render out each button here. Assign index to name and attach
          handleViewChange */}
      {buttonLabels.map((view, i) => (
        <button key={i} name={i} onClick={handleViewChange}>
          {view}
        </button>
      ))}

      {/* This will render the component for the specified view index. */}
      {views[viewIndex].component}

    </div>
  );
};

// Create a map of button name to corresponding component.
const views = [
  { name: "Employers", component: <Employers /> },
  { name: "Employees", component: <Employees /> },
  { name: "Contractors", component: <Contractors /> },
  { name: "Candidates", component: <Candidates /> }
];
```